# console.log to stdout on gulp events

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I want to log to stdout (the config environment) when a [gulp](http://gulpjs.com) task is running or has run.

Something like this:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
  var enviroment = argv.env || 'development';
  var config = gulp.src('config/' + enviroment + '.json')
      .pipe(ngConstant({name: 'app.config'}));
  var scripts = gulp.src('js/*');

  return es.merge(config, scripts)
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/dist'))
    .on('success', function() { 
      console.log('Configured environment: ' + environment);
    });
});
```

I am not sure what event I should be responding to or where to find a list of these. Any pointers? Many thanks.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

*(In December 2017, the `gulp-util` module, which provided logging, [was deprecated](https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5). The Gulp team recommended that developers replace this functionality with the `fancy-log` module. This answer has been updated to reflect that.)*

[`fancy-log`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fancy-log) provides logging and was originally built by the Gulp team.

```js
var log = require('fancy-log');
log('Hello world!');
```

To add logging, [Gulp's API documentation](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md) tell us that `.src` returns:

> Returns a stream of Vinyl files that can be piped to plugins.

Node.js's [`Stream`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) documentation provides a list of events. Put together, here's an example:

```js
gulp.task('default', function() {
    return gulp.src('main.scss')
        .pipe(sass({ style: 'expanded' }))
        .on('end', function(){ log('Almost there...'); })
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
        .on('end', function(){ log('Done!'); });
});
```

Note: The `end` event may be called before the plugin is complete (and has sent all of its own output), because the event is called when "all data has been flushed to the underlying system".

Comment: `.on('end', () => gutil.log('ES6 arrow syntax for simplicity...') )`

Comment: Any idea why a tool is needed at all?  Why doesn't `console.log` work?

Comment: @AlexMcMillan `.on('end', function(){ console.log('Almost there...'); })` works for me.

Comment: @AlexMcMillan It just pretty-prints the output in the same style as the rest of the log so you get timers.

Comment: As of today (December 2017), `gulp-util` has been deprecated: https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5

Answer (score 18):

*(PLEASE NOTE - In December 2017, the `gulp-util` module was deprecated.)*

To build on the answer by [Jacob Budin](http:///users/865601/jacob-budin), I recently tried this and found it useful.

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var util = require("gulp-util");
var changed = require("gulp-changed");

gulp.task("copyIfChanged", function() {
    var nSrc=0, nDes=0, dest="build/js";
    gulp.src("app/**/*.js")
    .on("data", function() { nSrc+=1;})
    .pipe(changed(dest)) //filter out src files not newer than dest
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest))
    .on("data", function() { nDes+=1;})
    .on("finish", function() {
        util.log("Results for app/**/*.js");
        util.log("# src files: ", nSrc);
        util.log("# dest files:", nDes);
    });
}
```

**Update (April 2021):**
Re the deprecated module issue.
Try replacing `util.log` from `require('gulp-util')` with `log` from `require('fancy-log')`. The rest of the approach should still work. Disclaimer: I haven't tested this.

Comment: `.on("end")` and `.on("finish")` differ by what?

Comment: As I understand it, `writable.on('finish')` will fire when `readable.on('end')` may not. The exact event may not matter in this case - I was more focused on logging useful stats.

Comment: [As per the current (7.5.0) documentation:](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_events_finish_and_end) "The `'finish'` and `'end'` events are from the `stream.Writable` and `stream.Readable` classes, respectively." @FrankNocke

Comment: `gulp-util` has been deprecated, use `fancy-log` instead

Answer (score 5):

Sadly `gulp.util` was deprecated.
Use `fancy-log` instead:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/fancy-log.