# Gulp not making bundle files

Tags: typescript, gulp

I am unable to get my bundle files created, this was working fine before I tried to upgrade to gulp4 and now that I am back on gulp3. I am not seeing the files in my `dist` folder. Gulp created the files in the `build` and `temp` folder but not in the `bundle` or `App` folder. Can I log the `task` at the end of the `createBundleTask` is get some type of status? Or is there some better way to trace this out?

task that is not building bundle files

```
var task = gulp.src(entryPoint)
    .pipe(gulp_jspm({
        selfExecutingBundle: true
    }),true)
    .pipe(rename(packageId + ".bundle.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + "/bundle"));
```

gulp file

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var runSequence = require("run-sequence");
var tslint = require("gulp-tslint");
var typedoc = require("gulp-typedoc");
var superstatic = require("superstatic");
var shell = require("gulp-shell");
var typescript = require("gulp-typescript");
var tsProject = typescript.createProject("tsconfig.json");
var sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");
var rimraf = require("gulp-rimraf");
var replace = require("gulp-replace");
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
var ignore = require("gulp-ignore");
var insert = require("gulp-insert");
var concat = require("gulp-concat");
var uglify = require("gulp-uglify");
var tslintStylish = require("gulp-tslint-stylish");
var util = require("gulp-util");
var commentSwap = require("gulp-comment-swap");
var tsc = require("gulp-typescript");
var gulp_jspm = require("gulp-jspm");
var inlineNg2Template = require("gulp-inline-ng2-template");

/**
 * Typescript configuration 
 **/
var paths = {
    dist: "./dist",    
    sources: "./App/**/*.ts"    
};

gulp.task("prod", function (callback) {
    runSequence(
        "compile",
        "bundle",
        "min",
        function (error) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error.message);
            } else {
                console.log("Production build finished successfully");
            }
            callback(error);
        });
});

/**
 * Compile TypeScript sources
 */
gulp.task("compile", ["clean"], function () {
    return gulp.src("./App/**/*.ts")
        .pipe(inlineNg2Template({
            base: "/",                  // Angular2 application base folder
            target: "es6",              // Can swap to es5
            indent: 2,                  // Indentation (spaces)
            useRelativePaths: false,     // Use components relative assset paths
            removeLineBreaks: false,     // Content will be included as one line
            templateExtension: ".html", // Update according to your file extension
            templateFunction: false    // If using a function instead of a string for `templateUrl`, pass a reference to that function here
        }))
        .pipe(tsProject())
        .pipe(ignore("References.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/App"));
});

/**
 * Bundle application parts
 */
gulp.task("bundle:template", function () {
    return createBundleTask(paths.dist + "/App/Pages/TemplateEdit.js", "template");
});

gulp.task("bundle:agents", function () {
    return createBundleTask(paths.dist + "/App/Pages/Maintenance/Agents.js", "agents");
});

gulp.task("bundle:indications", function () {
    return createBundleTask(paths.dist + "/App/Pages/Maintenance/Indications.js", "indications");
});

gulp.task("bundle:styleguidenotes", function () {
    return createBundleTask(paths.dist + "/App/Components/NoteEditor/NoteEditor.js", "styleguidenotes");
});

gulp.task("bundle:dynamicdictionary", function () {
    return createBundleTask(paths.dist + "/App/Pages/Maintenance/DynamicDictionary.js", "dynamicdictionary");
});

gulp.task("bundle:splitdynamicdictionary", function () {
    return createBundleTask(paths.dist + "/App/Pages/Maintenance/SplitDynamicDictionary.js", "splitdynamicdictionary");
});

gulp.task("bundle:styleguidenotesdevprocess", function () {
    return createBundleTask(paths.dist + "/App/Pages/StyleGuideNote/Index.js", "styleguidenotesdevprocess");
});

gulp.task("bundle:scheduling", function () {
    return createBundleTask(paths.dist + "/App/Pages/Scheduling/Index.js", "scheduling");
});

gulp.task("bundle:templatesmanagement", function () {
    return createBundleTask(paths.dist + "/App/Pages/TemplatesManagement/Index.js", "templatesmanagement");
});

gulp.task("bundle:review", function () {
    return createBundleTask(paths.dist + "/App/Pages/Review/Index.js", "review");
});

gulp.task("bundle:ownedreview", function () {
    return createBundleTask(paths.dist + "/App/Pages/OwnedReview/Index.js", "ownedreview");
});

gulp.task("bundle:pdfqueue", function () {
    return createBundleTask(paths.dist + "/App/Pages/PdfQueue/Index.js", "pdfqueue");
});

gulp.task("bundle:admin", function () {
    return createBundleTask(paths.dist + "/App/Pages/Admin/Index.js", "admin");
});


gulp.task("bundle", function (callback) {
    runSequence(
        "bundle:template",
        "bundle:agents",
        "bundle:indications",
        "bundle:styleguidenotes",        
        "bundle:dynamicdictionary",
        "bundle:splitdynamicdictionary",
        "bundle:styleguidenotesdevprocess",
        "bundle:scheduling",
        "bundle:templatesmanagement",
        "bundle:review",
        "bundle:ownedreview",
        "bundle:pdfqueue",
        "bundle:admin",
        function (error) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error.message);
            } else {
                console.log("Bundling finished successfully");
            }
            callback(error);
        });
});

/**
 * Create application package
 */
gulp.task("min:template", function () {
    return createProductionPackageTask("template", true);
});

gulp.task("min:agents", function () {
    return createProductionPackageTask("agents", false);
});

gulp.task("min:indications", function () {
    return createProductionPackageTask("indications", false);
});

gulp.task("min:styleguidenotes", function () {
    return createProductionPackageTask("styleguidenotes", false);
});

gulp.task("min:dynamicdictionary", function () {
    return createProductionPackageTask("dynamicdictionary", false);
});

gulp.task("min:splitdynamicdictionary", function () {
    return createProductionPackageTask("splitdynamicdictionary", false);
});

gulp.task("min:styleguidenotesdevprocess", function () {
    return createProductionPackageTask("styleguidenotesdevprocess", false);
});

gulp.task("min:scheduling", function () {
    return createProductionPackageTask("scheduling", false);
});


gulp.task("min:templatesmanagement", function () {
    return createProductionPackageTask("templatesmanagement", false);
});

gulp.task("min:review", function () {
    return createProductionPackageTask("review", false);
});

gulp.task("min:ownedreview", function () {
    return createProductionPackageTask("ownedreview", false);
});

gulp.task("min:pdfqueue", function () {
    return createProductionPackageTask("pdfqueue", false);
});
gulp.task("min:admin", function () {
    return createProductionPackageTask("admin", false);
});

gulp.task("min", function (callback) {
    runSequence(
        "min:template",
        "min:agents",
        "min:indications",
        "min:styleguidenotes",        
        "min:dynamicdictionary",
        "min:splitdynamicdictionary",
        "min:styleguidenotesdevprocess",
        "min:scheduling",
        "min:templatesmanagement",
        "min:review",
        "min:ownedreview",
        "min:pdfqueue",
        "min:admin",
        function (error) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error.message);
            } else {
                console.log("Minification finished successfully");
            }
            callback(error);
        });
});

/**
 * Clean build folder
 */
gulp.task("clean", function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.dist, { read: false }).pipe(rimraf({ force: true }));
});

/**
 * Helper methods
 */
var createBundleTask = function (entryPoint, packageId) {
    if (typeof entryPoint === "undefined") {
        throw "ArgumentNullException: entryPoint";
    }

    if (typeof packageId === "undefined") {
        throw "ArgumentNullException: packageId";
    }

    var task = gulp.src(entryPoint)
        .pipe(gulp_jspm({ selfExecutingBundle: true }))
        .pipe(rename(packageId + ".bundle.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + "/bundle"));

    return task;
};

var createProductionPackageTask = function (packageId, uglifyDestination) {
    if (typeof packageId === "undefined") {
        throw "ArgumentNullException: packageId";
    }

    var filesArry = [
        "./node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js",
        "./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js",
        "./node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js",
        paths.dist + "/bundle/" + packageId + ".bundle.js"
    ];

    var task = gulp.src(filesArry)
        .pipe(concat(packageId + "_concatApp.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + "/temp"))
        .pipe(rename(packageId + ".bundle.min.js"));



    if (uglifyDestination) {
        task = task.pipe(uglify({ mangle: false }));
    }

    return task.pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + "/build"));    
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gulp 4 removed the 3-arguments syntax for `gulp.task`, as mentioned in the [changelog](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp).

This means dependency tasks should now be handled differently, using the two new functions:

- `gulp.series()`
- `gulp.parallel()`

You can read more about this breaking change in this [migration guide](https://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/complete-guide-upgrading-gulp-4/).

So you have 2 changes to make:

1. Currently, in your gulp file you have this task:

   ```
   gulp.task("compile", ["clean"], function () {
       ...
   });
   ```

   So you must change it to:

   ```
   gulp.task('compile', gulp.series('clean', function() {
      ...
   }));
   ```
2. Similairly, you must replace `runSequence` with `task.series` or `task.parallel` (only you know if those tasks must run serially or in parallel).

   Another option is to update the Gulp 3-compatible package `run-sequence` which you currently use to the Gulp 4-compatible package [gulp4-run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp4-run-sequence).

Comment: so with Gulp3 i can use this run-sequence form gulp 4 to correct the bundle ?

Comment: when I install `+ gulp4-run-sequence@1.0.1` I am then seeing this `Error: Cannot find module 'typedoc'`

Comment: @Jefferson, this is unrelated to `gulp4-run-sequence` itself, because it actually has no dependencies. I've just run `npm i gulp4-run-sequence` on my machine, and it installed without errors. Maybe try to first uninstall `run-sequence` (the previous version), and then try to reinstall `gulp4-run-sequence`. If it doesn't help, you probably have some module which require `typedoc`, so just go through the usual ways to resolve it ([maybe this would help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023672/how-do-i-resolve-cannot-find-module-error-using-node-js)).

Comment: @Jefferson, regardless, as mentioned in my answer, you can completely remove `runSequence` and replace it with `task.series` or `task.parallel`.

Comment: is there a way I can log that `.pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + "/bundle"));` I would like to see an error?

Comment: @Jefferson you can log the error by using `.on('error', function (err) { console.error(err.message); })` after the `.pipe()`. You can also listen to all other [stream events](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_events_finish_and_end). see also this [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27975129/console-log-to-stdout-on-gulp-events).